# Set each individual column to have its own datatype

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, types

How can I set a particular datatype for every single column?

I opened a `.txt` file which has 236 columns with Pandas.

For example I have a column with values called "System Time", another one called "Temperature", another one called "Alarm", ...

For "System Time" I want to use `DateTime`, for "Temperature" I want to use `float` because the values have decimal numbers (e.g. `24.4`) and for the "Alarm" I want to use `string`.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

When Pandas reads your file (e.g. using `pd.read_csv`) to construct the DataFrame it will automatically select the appropriate datatype (`dtype`) to hold the data on a column by column basis. This means that a column of decimal numbers will have the `float64` type, and so on.

If you have as many as 236 columns, it's probably easiest to let Pandas figure out the best datatypes.

Dates can be trickier to handle, so you might want to be more explicit about which columns Pandas should parse to the `datetime` type. You could do this after you've built the DataFrame with `pd.to_datetime(df["System Time"])`.

---

If however you'd like to control the datatype of each column during the construction, many Pandas methods allow you pass in a list or dictionary of columns names and what their types should be.

For example, if you use [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), you can make use of the `dtype` keyword argument:

> `dtype` : *Type name or dict of column -> type*
>
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. `{'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32}`

For instance, you might choose to construct you DataFrame in a manner similar to this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', names=["Temperature", "Alarm"],
                  dtypes=[np.float64, object])
```

N.B. There is no `string` datatype available in Pandas; such values usually have the datatype `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all elements of column using `astype(<Type>)`.

Let's go through this quick example to explain how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
x = [['0.3', '13', '14','03/22/2015'], ['1', '89', '3','24/02/2014'], ['4', '23', '0','04/13/2013']]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['A', 'B', 'C','D'])

print df.dtypes
```

The Output: The type of every column is "Object"

```
A    object
B    object
C    object
D    object
dtype: object
```

By using `astype(<Type>)`, we can convert the type.

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float)   # To Float
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(str)     # To Str
df['C'] = df['C'].astype(int)     # To Int
df['D'] = pd.to_datetime(df['D']) # To DateTime

print df.dtypes
```

The result:

```
A           float64
B            object
C             int64
D    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

You can also assign type after reading the CSV File, by using `dtype` and :

```
`df= pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype={'A':float})`
```